# UPS Worldship Integration and .net

Tags: .net, ups-worldship

Are there any UPS WorldShip integration APIS or Libraries out there for .net? I've been tasked with integrating our Sample Order application (A VB.Net/SQL Server app) with UPS, and having it write .xml files for the auto import feature though serialization has gotten my foot in the door- but some of the more advanced shipment options such as international customs options are completely undocumented.

How did you get UPS integration up and running? Did you have any 3rd party help doing it? Is there a better location for documentation I'm just missing?

**EDIT**: What I'm trying to do is create new shipments based on order data in my database and then update those orders with the tracking number the shipment received from UPS. The orders have the shipping method designated, 2nd Day Air, Ground, or International. About 50% of the orders are international.

Comment: my our c# based win apps we generate UPS label. what kind of information u r looking for...what is ur requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here:
http://www.ups.com/content/us/en/bussol/offering/technology/alliances/technology_tools.html

Look at the NexxStatus and ShipRush products at the bottom.  Hopefully between those you'll be able to find something.

Answer (score 1):

The shiprush SDK can be really useful for making shipping labels. It does UPS, postal, and FedEx.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the 3rd party libraries are nice, but technically not required.

Here's what your really need:

1. UPS Account
2. UPS Account Number
3. UPS Access Key

Then download their developer kit:
see folder:
Rating PACKAGE\PACKAGE Web Services\Code Samples\Rate\Dot Net\RateWSSample\RateWSSample

Comment: I can't seem to find #'s 1-3 after creating a MyUPS account.  Do I need to sign up for a full business account to test?

Or should I just get this from the business I'm implementing it for?

Answer (score 0):

I found the small [dotnetshipping](https://github.com/rlaneve/dotNETShipping) library by Ryan LaNeve to be helpful in getting started with UPS integration.

Granted, this is more geared towards using their Rates & Service Selection service, as opposed to WorldShip. Might be worth a look though...

Comment: I am frustrated by the fact that this library shows different rate amount and guaranteed delivery dates that the UPS web site does. Sometimes they vary considerably. The library also lists services not available on the web. Anyone have better experience?

Answer (score 0):

What are you specifically trying to do with UPS integration? Get shipping costs? Get tracking information? If you have a specific question, please post and maybe I can help.

http://www.ups.com/e_comm_access/gettools_index?loc=en_US

Download the documentation. There is a zip file with XML integration that has all the fields you need.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the xml integration .zip you're speaking of- could you give me a direct link?

Answer (score 0):

We found that InterShipper has a VERY easy integration tool to FEDEx, UPS, USPS, DHL.  It is all based upon a RESTfull API.  The response is a simple XML.  It returns rates, labels, and billing information for the major carriers.

http://www.intershipper.com/

This is just a suggestion.